# Failed to install laravel-setup-wizard

Tags: laravel-5, wizard

In my Laravel 5.6 application I tried to install [laravel-setup-wizard](http://%20https://github.com/marvinlabs/laravel-setup-wizard)
plugin and got error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for marvinlabs/laravel-setup-wizard ^0.2.1 -> satisfiable by marvinlabs/laravel-setup-wizard[0.2.1].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - marvinlabs/laravel-setup-wizard 0.2.1 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.13 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.19 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.27 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.36 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.9 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.6.33].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.6.33, required as 5.6.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.33].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have :

```
$ php artisan --version 
Laravel Framework 5.6.33
```

1) Does it mean that this plugin is not suitable for laravel 5.6 project?
If there is a way to install it somehow?

2) Can you advice some plugin/script compatible with bootstrap 4.1 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this means it is compatible with Laravel 5.4 and not with 5.6.

I scrolled through the readme, didn't really do any real research, but i found this:

> Credits:
>
> Some code is taken from another similar project: RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller

Maybe take a look there?

EDIT: I see now that the code has not been updated for over a year. Maybe it is not the best decision to look at libraries which are not in active development. Try to look for something more active. Also, someone opened an issue on the repo almost a year ago that it is not compatible with Laravel 5.5 (So you can conclude altogether it also wont work with Laravel 5.6). To which the author replied that Pull Requests are welcome and that was it, it seems the repo owner wont put any effort in it anymore.